# apache 2.4 .htaccess Internal Server Error (.htaccess not working)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want use .htaccess but if  I try add `RewriteEngine  on` to file and when I refresh web page I get `Internal Server Error` on apache 2.4  also I added to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Why error occurs?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545442/htaccess-file-causing-internal-server-error). Have you checked the apache error log? Maybe mod_rewrite isn't enabled?

Comment: In log I found `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. As root, run `a2enmod rewrite` followed by `apachectl restart`.